# Configuring the section with \renewcommand in the appendix won't work

Tags: sectioning, numbering, appendices

My appendix consits of a chapter which tells the TOC that an appendix exists. All other headings in my appendix are sections.

Now I want that a section header looks like:

> Appendix A. Some Text
>
> Appendix B. Some Text
>
> Appendix C. Some Text

But the following line

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
```

which can be found on most of the appendix articles won't work.

My minimal example looks like the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,headsepline,smallheadings,parident, numbers=noenddot, appendixprefix=true]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{appendix}
...

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter1}
\section{Section1}
\section{Section2}

%Appendix
\appendix
\renewcommand\thesection{\appendixname\ \Alph{section}}
\pagestyle{empty}

%for linking the appendix to toc without pagenumber
\phantomsection
\hypertarget{link.appendix}{}
\addchap*{Anhang}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\usekomafont{chapterentry}%
  \protect\hyperlink{link.appendix}{Anhang}}

\refstepcounter{chapter}
\newpage

%other try ...
%\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}

\section*{Class diagram} \label{class-diagram}
\section*{List of UI-Elementen} \label{list-ui-elements}
\section*{CD}
\end{document}
```

Comment: okay, I use section and no its displayed as I wanted. But it's is shown in the toc, how does it use my "layout" and doesn't show up in the toc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you are using the starred version of `\section` with a label. This version doesn't provide any anchors for the label so your labeling false. A simple example shows this behavior.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document} 
\section*{Class diagram} \label{class-diagram}
\ref{class-diagramm}
\end{document}
```

The redefinition of `\thesection` doesn't influence the command `\section*` because `\section*` print only formated text with a predefined skip above and below.

Nevertheless you can do the following. Use `\section` instead of `\section*`. The benefits

- you can work with the redefinition of `\thesection`,
- you can use the label and
- you get the correct headings.

With the current settings the section will be shown up in the toc. Avoiding this you can set the counter `tocdepth` to zero after the command `appendix.

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
```